# JavaScript Micro-Templating .How loading file template?

Tags: javascript, template-engine

Good JavaScript Micro-Templating by John Resig http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

I want to dynamically load templates

```
function loader(file) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: file
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        console.log(msg);
        tmpl("item_tmpl", dataObject);
    });
loader('temp.html');
```

**temp.html**

```
<script type="text/html" id="item_tmpl">
    <%=text%>
    <%=prof%>"/>    
</script>
```

but I have error 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null**

Upd:

correct example http://jsfiddle.net/tomo_thumb/27xEf/3/light/

I just need to transfer templates to external files and loader them ...

Comment: `dataObject` appear `undefined` ? Tried substituting `msg` for `dataObject` at `tmpl("item_tmpl", dataObject);` ,  e.g.;  `tmpl("item_tmpl", msg);` ?

Comment: no.... dataObject passes correct. Global var.